# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) in C

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

Im beginner of C programming..
When I build the proj, memory Thread was occurred in "matrixInit" func.
Idk why is it happen..
I want to solve this problem, so can you tell the reason why this thread was occurred and how can I solve it?

(compiled in Xcode)

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "array2DvariableSize.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    item a[] = {1,2,3,2,3,4,1,2,2};
    item b[] = {2,4,3,4,3,4,1,5,2};

    Matrix *m1 = matrixNew(3, 3);
    matrixInit(m1, a);
    matrixPrint(m1);

    Matrix *m2 = matrixNew(3, 3);
    matrixInit(m2, b);
    matrixPrint(m2);

    Matrix *m3;
    m3 = matrixAdd(m1, m2);
    matrixPrint(m3);

    matrixFree(m1);
    matrixFree(m2);
    matrixFree(m3);
    return 0;

}
```

array2DvariableSize.h

```
#ifndef array2DvariableSize_h
#define array2DvariableSize_h

#include <stdio.h>
typedef int item;
typedef struct {
    int col;
    int row;
    item** var;
}Matrix;

Matrix* matrixNew(int row, int col);
void matrixInit(Matrix* m, item* src);
void matrixFree(Matrix* m);
Matrix* matrixMultiply(const Matrix* a, const Matrix* b);
Matrix* matrixAdd(const Matrix* a,const Matrix* b);
void matrixPrint(Matrix* m);
#endif /* array2DvariableSize_h */
```

array2DvariableSize.c

```
#include "array2DvariableSize.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

Matrix* matrixNew(int row, int col){
    Matrix* m;

    m = (Matrix*)malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
    m -> row = row;
    m -> col = col;
    m -> var = (item**)malloc(sizeof(item*)*row);
    for (int i = 0; i<row; i++){
         m->var[i] = (item*)malloc(sizeof(item)*col);
         memset(m->var[i], 0, sizeof(item)*col);
    }
}
    return m;
}

void matrixFree(Matrix* m){
    for (int i = 0 ; i < m -> row; i++){
        free(m->var[i]);
    }
    free(m->var);
    free(m);
}
void matrixInit(Matrix* m, item* src){
    for(int j = 0 ; j< m->row; j++){
        for(int i = 0; i < m->col; i++){
            m->var[j][i] = src[j*m->col + i]; // Thread occurred in herd

        }
    }
}

Matrix* matrixAdd(const Matrix* a, const Matrix* b){
    Matrix* m;
    if(a->col != b->col || a->row != b->row) return NULL;

    m = matrixNew(a->row, a->col);
    for(int j = 0; j < a->row; j++){
        for(int i = 0; i < a->col; i++){
            m->var[j][i] = a->var[j][i] + b->var[j][i];
        }
    }
    return m;
}

Matrix* matrixMultiply(const Matrix* a, const Matrix* b){
    Matrix* m;
    int col, row, iter;
    if(a->col != b->row) return NULL;
    row = a->row;
    col = b->col;
    iter = a->col;

    m = matrixNew(row, col);
    for (int j = 0; j<row; j++){
        for(int i= 0; i< col; i++){
            for(int k = 0; k < iter; k++){
                m->var[j][i] += a->var[j][k] * b->var[k][i];
            }
        }
    }
    return m;
}

void matrixPrint(Matrix* m){
    for(int j = 0; j < m->row; j++){
        for(int i = 0; i < m->col; i++){
            printf("%5d", m->var[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Thanks to read my question :)

Comment: [Allocate memory 2d array in function C](//stackoverflow.com/q/15062718)

Comment: Well clearly you allocated enough memory for one row in your matrix. Just change in `matrixNew` the line `m->var = malloc(sizeof(item) * row * col);`. Moreover, one doesn't cast the return of `malloc`.

Comment: You seem to have a different understanding of the term "thread" than many others on this site. Just to avoid confusion for yourself, you might want to check out the other possible meanings.

Comment: oh I changed the matrixNew func

Comment: Thanks to all you guys to solve the problem. I found that I used a wrong variable xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void matrixInit(Matrix* m, item* src){
    for(int j = 0 ; j< m->row; j++){
        for(int i = 0; i < m->col; j++){
            m->var[j][i] = src[j*m->col + i]; // Thread occurred in herd

        }
    }
}
```

The reason why thread occured was.. I used 'j' instead of 'i' ....Lmao..